# Applying :host css based on ancestor

Tags: css, shadow-dom

We have an app with two themes, call them "light" and "dark." They're applied to `<body>` like so:

```
<body class="dark'>
  ...
</body>
```

Then I have a web component that uses the shadow DOM, and I need to apply some styles to that component based on what theme is applied to `<body>`.

The most obvious solution is to use `host-context`:

```
:host-context(body.dark) h1 {
  color: white;
}
```

This works great...with Chrome. Sadly, Safari and Firefox [don't do host-context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host-context()#browser_compatibility).

Is there a way to accomplish the same thing just using `:host`? Some other method?